# Extract words that are repeated from one sentence to the next

Tags: r, regex

I have sentences from spoken conversation and would like to identify the words that are repeated fom sentence to sentence; here's some illustartive data (in reproducible format below)

```
df
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   Orthographic                                                                                      
   <chr>                                                                                             
 1 "like I don't understand sorry like how old's your mom"                                           
 2 "eh sixty-one"                                                                                    
 3 "yeah (...) yeah yeah like I mean she's not like in the risk age group but still"                 
 4 "yeah"                                                                                            
 5 "HH"                                                                                              
 6 "I don't know"                                                                                    
 7 "yeah I talked to my grandparents last night and last time I talked to them it was like two weeks…
 8 "yeah"                                                                                            
 9 "she said you should come home probably "                                                         
10 "no and like why would you go to the airport where people have corona sit in the plane where peop…
```

I'm not unsuccessful at extracting the repeated words using a `for`loop but do also get some strange results: Here's what I've been doing so far:

```
# initialize pattern and new column `rept` in `df`:
pattern1 <- c()
df$rept <- NA

# for loop:
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  pattern1[i-1] <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(unlist(str_split(df$Orthographic[i-1], " ")), collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
  df$rept[i] <- str_extract_all(df$Orthographic[i], pattern1[i-1])
}
```

The results are these; result # 10 is strange/incorrect - it should be `character(0)`. How can the code be improved so that no such strange results are obtained?

```
df$rept
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "yeah"

[[5]]
character(0)

[[6]]
character(0)

[[7]]
[1] "I"     "I"     "don't" "I"     "I"     "don't" "I"    

[[8]]
[1] "yeah"

[[9]]
character(0)

[[10]]
 [1] ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    "you" ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
[17] ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
[33] ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
[49] ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""   
[65] ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""
```

**Reproducible data**:

```
structure(list(Orthographic = c("like I don't understand sorry like how old's your mom", 
"eh sixty-one", "yeah (...) yeah yeah like I mean she's not like in the risk age group but still", 
"yeah", "HH", "I don't know", "yeah I talked to my grandparents last night and last time I talked to them it was like two weeks ago and they at that time they were already like maybe you should just get on a plane and come home and like you can't just be here and and then last night they were like are you sure you don't wanna come home and I was I don't think I can and my mom said the same thing", 
"yeah", "she said you should come home probably ", "no and like why would you go to the airport where people have corona sit in the plane where people have corona to get there where people have corona and then go and take it to your family"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: If you wonder what the problem is with your approach: there is a trailing whitespace in the line before Line 10, and when splitting with space, there is an empty item in the resulting list. Hence, your pattern includes  an empty  `|` alternative, that just matches any position in the string. Your approach with regex is wrong: you are using word boundaries when splitting with whitespace. You need to use whitespace boundaries in this case and *escape* the special chars in each chunk before using in the regex pattern.

Comment: That's incredibly helpful, thank you! I've overlooked the whitespace, indeed. I don't understand what you mean by "whitespace boundaries" and by advising to "escape the special chars in each chunk before using in the regex pattern" -- how would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you debug such regex issues concerning dynamic patterns with word boundaries, there are a lot of things to keep in mind (so as to understand how to best approach the whole issue).

First, check the patterns you get,

```r
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {
    pattern1[i-1] <- paste0("(?<!\\S)(?:", paste0(escape.for.regex(unlist(str_split(trimws(df$Orthographic[i-1]), "\\s+"))), collapse = "|"), ")(?!\\S)")
    df$rept[i] <- str_extract_all(df$Orthographic[i], pattern1[i-1])
}
```

Here is the list of regexps:

```r
[1] "\\b(like|I|don't|understand|sorry|like|how|old's|your|mom)\\b"
[1] "\\b(eh|sixty-one)\\b"
[1] "\\b(yeah|(...)|yeah|yeah|like|I|mean|she's|not|like|in|the|risk|age|group|but|still)\\b"
[1] "\\b(yeah)\\b"
[1] "\\b(HH)\\b"
[1] "\\b(I|don't|know)\\b"
[1] "\\b(yeah|I|talked|to|my|grandparents|last|night|and|last|time|I|talked|to|them|it|was|like|two|weeks|ago|and|they|at|that|time|they|were|already|like|maybe|you|should|just|get|on|a|plane|and|come|home|and|like|you|can't|just|be|here|and|and|then|last|night|they|were|like|are|you|sure|you|don't|wanna|come|home|and|I|was|I|don't|think|I|can|and|my|mom|said|the|same|thing)\\b"
[1] "\\b(yeah)\\b"
[1] "\\b(she|said|you|should|come|home|probably|)\\b"
```

Look at the second pattern: `\b(eh|sixty-one)\b`. What if the first word was `sixty`? The `\b(sixty|sixty-one)\b` regex will never match `sixty-one` because `sixty` would have matched first and the other alternative would not even have been considered. You need to always sort the alternatives by length in the descending order to assure you always match the longest alternative first when you use word boundaries and you know there can be alternatives with more than one word in them. *Here*, you do not need to sort the alternatives because you only have single word alternatives.

See the next pattern containing `|(...)|` alternative. It matches any three chars other than line break chars and captures them into a group. However, the string contained a `(...)` substring where the parentheses and dots are literal chars. To match them with a regex, you need to *escape* all special chars.

Next, you consider "words" to be *non-whitespace chunks of chars* because you use `str_split(df$Orthographic[i-1], " ")`. This invalidates the approach with `\b` altogether, you need to use *whitespace boundaries*, `(?<!\S)` at the start and `(?!\S)` at the end instead of `\b`s. *More*, since you only split with a *single space*, you may get empty alternatives if there are two or more consecutive spaces in the input string. You need to use `\s+` pattern here to split by one or more whitespaces.

Next, there is a trailing space in the last but one string, and it creates an empty alternative. You need to `trimws` your input before splitting into tokens/words.

This is what you need to do with the regex solution: add the `escape.for.regex` function:

```r
## Escape for regex
escape.for.regex <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^${|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}
```

and then use it to escape the tokens that you obtain by splitting the trimmed `df$Orthographic[i-1]` with `\s+` regex, appy `unique` to remove duplicates to make the pattern more efficient and shorter, and add the whitespace boundaries:

```r
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
    pattern1[i-1] <- paste0("(?<!\\S)(?:", paste0(escape.for.regex(unique(unlist(str_split(trimws(df$Orthographic[i-1]), "\\s+")))), collapse = "|"), ")(?!\\S)")
    df$rept[i] <- str_extract_all(df$Orthographic[i], pattern1[i-1])
}
```

See the list of regexps:

```r
[1] "(?<!\\S)(?:like|I|don't|understand|sorry|how|old's|your|mom)(?!\\S)"
[1] "(?<!\\S)(?:eh|sixty-one)(?!\\S)"
[1] "(?<!\\S)(?:yeah|\\(\\.\\.\\.\\)|like|I|mean|she's|not|in|the|risk|age|group|but|still)(?!\\S)"
[1] "(?<!\\S)(?:yeah)(?!\\S)"
[1] "(?<!\\S)(?:HH)(?!\\S)"
[1] "(?<!\\S)(?:I|don't|know)(?!\\S)"
[1] "(?<!\\S)(?:yeah|I|talked|to|my|grandparents|last|night|and|time|them|it|was|like|two|weeks|ago|they|at|that|were|already|maybe|you|should|just|get|on|a|plane|come|home|can't|be|here|then|are|sure|don't|wanna|think|can|mom|said|the|same|thing)(?!\\S)"
[1] "(?<!\\S)(?:yeah)(?!\\S)"
[1] "(?<!\\S)(?:she|said|you|should|come|home|probably)(?!\\S)"
```

Output:

```r
> df$rept
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "yeah"

[[5]]
character(0)

[[6]]
character(0)

[[7]]
[1] "I"     "I"     "don't" "I"     "I"     "don't" "I"    

[[8]]
[1] "yeah"

[[9]]
character(0)

[[10]]
[1] "you"
```

Comment: That's really amazing! Your time, effort and expertise is very much appreciated!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I forgot about applying `unique` to the list of tokens, this will make the pattern more succint. Just added to the answer.

Comment: One last question: why not use `(?<=\\s)` and `(?=\\s)` as whitespace boundaries?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann `(?<=\s)` *requires* a whitespace to appear immediately to the left of the current position and `(?=\s)` *requires* a whitespace to appear immediately to the right of the current position, i.e. the start and end of string positions are not accounted for. `(?<!\S)` = `(?<=\s|^)` and `(?!\S)` = `(?=\s|$)`, i.e. matches at the start and end of string will get matched if followed/preceded with a whitespace char.

Comment: Ah, okay, makes sense! Again much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether it is sufficient to identify repeated words, or also their repeat frequencies, you might want to modify the function, but here is one approach using the `dplyr::lead` function:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# general function that identifies intersecting words from multiple strings
getRpt <- function(...){
  l <- lapply(list(...), function(x) unlist(unique(
    str_split(as.character(x), pattern=boundary(type="word")))))
  Reduce(intersect, l)
}

df$rept <- mapply(getRpt, df$Orthographic, lead(df$Orthographic), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How would it be possible to display the repeated word next to the line in which it **re**-occurs? In the current solution it is displayed one row above.